# Can I call a function that calls store.dispatch from within a functional component or do I have to use useDispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux, functional-programming, react-hooks

The following code works, but I'm new to react hooks, and I want to know if there's a reason why I shouldn't do it this way.  I am looking to be able to call the readData function from multiple components and also at the top of the app.  (This is an abbreviated version of the code.)

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
     //
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

function readData(){
  axios.get("https://...")
    .then((response) => {
        store.dispatch({type: "dataRead", message:"dataRead", data: response.data})
    });
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <LoadBtn/>
        <Display/>
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

function LoadBtn(){

  function handleClick(){
    readData();
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>LOAD BTN</div>
  )
  
}

function Display(){
   const data = useSelector(state => state.data);

   const loading = <div>Loading ...</div>

   if (data != []){
    loading = <div>{data[0].bio}</div>
   } 

   return (
      {loading}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[You should never import the store directly into your React components](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).  Always use the React-Redux APIs to interact with the store inside components, such as `useDispatch`.

Comment: I'm not sure I am importing a store into a component.  The function that calls it is vanilla and outside of react.  But I am calling that function within a component.  Can you clarify?  In any case, what I want to know is WHY you shouldn't do this.  The linked doc says don't do it in case you do x or y, and I know I won't be doing x or y.  In that scenario, is there a reason not to do it this way?

Comment: @toyko, `LoadButton` component calls `readData` that directly refers to result of `createStore`